# SSH : ssh-keygen generating rsa key, but not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am using `ssh-keygen` and giving no pass phrase then key-fingerprint is successfully generated and shown.
Then I'm giving `ssh-copy-id user@localhost` then its prompting for my user's password after providing it states `Number of key(s) added : 1`.
Now if I'm doing `ssh localhost` its again prompting for password.
also If I do `ssh user@localhost` it asks for password.

PS : I have used : `ssh-add` and also `sudo ufw allow 22`  nothing seems to work fine everytime I do `ssh localhost` I have been prompted with password.

[EDIT]

`ssh -v localhost`
shows

> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
>   debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b2:58:a9:da:84:3f:43:1c:86:51:ba:cd:b7:88:a3:74
>   debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/harsh/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/harsh/.ssh/id_dsa
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/harsh/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/harsh/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/harsh/.ssh/id_ed25519
>   debug1: Next authentication method: password
>   harsh@localhost's password:

Comment: Is your public key in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: You can run `ssh -v user@localhost` and inspect debug output to see what private keys are tried by ssh client, and what are the outcomes.

Comment: @knittl yes public key is there

Comment: Trying Private Key `.ssh/id_ecdsa` and `.ssh/id_ed25519` and then it shows Next authentication method : password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this problem by simply re-installing the `ssh` on my ubuntu machine.

The problem was because `ssh` wasn't installed properly upon `OS` installation.

Answer (score 1):

I would check these:

- make sure that the remote .ssh directory and authorized_keys file have proper permissions

  - both should be owned by you
  - permissions should be 0700 (rwx:---:---) on $HOME/.ssh and
  - 0600 (rw-:---:---) on $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
- verify that the ssh daemon allows for key auth, i.e. for openssh server there should be this line in its config:

  - PubkeyAuthentication yes

Then re-run your ssh command with debugging output enabled

- ssh -v yourhost

It will show you which authentication methods it is going to try, i.e.

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey`

Good luck! :)

Comment: `Authentications that can be continue : publickey,password` 
`debug 1 : Next authentication method: publickey`
but still in the end its trying private key and after that comes for password !! don't know why.

Comment: I keep getting `debug1: identity file /home/yuri/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/yuri/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the setup where the **/home** directory was mounted via NFS (Network File System). Bellow command did the job.

`[root@localhost]# setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs=true`